# Getting a UK visa after a 10 year ban

Tags: uk, visa-bans

I am a British citizen living in the UK but have a fiancee living outside the country. She was banned in 2009 when she applied to come to study in the UK. Her agent included a fake bank statement which led to the 10 year ban.

We are planning to marry sometime in 2019 which makes 10 years after the ban, can you please advice us if she might have difficulty gaining entrance to the UK or will this be a straight forward application as long as she mentions that she was banned and refused entry 10 years ago and now all current documents are genuine?

Comment: One wonders why it's the *customer* and not the *agent* who gets banned in those situations...

Comment: @GregHewgill It's the applicant who signs the visa application form and submits it, along with the fake documents.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's true, but one still suspects that in cases like this negative consequences for the agent would be more helpful than negative consequences for the applicant.

Comment: @phoog Oh, it would be helpful, but agents continue doing this because it's virtually free money for them with little consequence. The UK has very few options to hold a foreign national in a foreign country accountable for this sort of thing.

Comment: The customer in this case did not submit the form and documents but the agent.

Comment: @phoog the latest ruling by the Court of Appeal says that deception is a seperate thing to prove than submission of false documents. False documents would lead to refusal of the application but the ECO would have to prove, on a balance of probabilities, that the applicant was aware of the fake documents for a ban. If the ECO is unable to prove that or the applicant is able to refute the allegations, a ban wouldn't apply. However, since the standard of proof is a balance of probabilities, it will be difficult for the OP to show the agent acted without the OP'S knowledge.